# Define the word "parse" for a non-technical user in 1-2 sentences

Tags: terminology

I am looking for a sentence or two to define the word "parse" to a non-technical user.

The file they upload may contain three types of lines and I need to recognize the type and parse accordingly.

What would be a good definition / explanation of "parse"?

They know what Load File means (button).
Then they Parse (button) and examine the output.
If the output looks correct they know they can Upload (button).
Some of the input is trashed such that the rules don't pick it up and needs visual inspection.  They may even still Upload if it is not perfect.

I am just trying to describe what this Parse button does at an abstract semi-technical level.  If this belongs on another site then let me know.  Not looking for help on how to lay out the page.

Thanks for all the freedback and so appreciate the UX side.  I have some non-technical users and on the other end it has to stand up to technical rigor.  I get you are probably going to hate this be so far I have gone with

```
Parse is a computer term for breaking down a structured or semi structured file   
Much like you might break down a sentence
```

Comment: Why not use the definition from the dictionary?

Comment: Why have a "Parse" button at all? Why not parse the file directly upon loading the file?

Comment: @Geier User can set parse options / parameters

Comment: @KenMohnkern The?  Which the?

Comment: We need more context. What is the user doing with this file. What is their objective.

Comment: @DA01 They are parsing. The purpose is not to describe THIS parse.  I simply want a good definition of the the word "Parse" for a non-technical user.

Comment: If the user doesn't even know what parsing is, then why are you exposing them to that information in the first place? It's not good UX to expose the user to information they don't understand and don't need to know.

Comment: @Frisbee definitions can differ in different context. Context is everything.

Comment: @DA01 The user isn't really parsing anything. The computer's doing the parsing. What is the _user_ doing with this file?

Comment: @Ajedi32 well, it seems like the user is doing *something* (ie, hitting the button called 'parse') But I agree...I think this is the wrong term in the context of the user's objectives here.

Comment: If the OP simply wants a generic definition, I'd argue this should instead be asked at English.se

Comment: **Validate** or **Preview**

Comment: @DA01 In the Enslish langues parse mean a lot of things like parse a sentence.  Parse in computer terms is very specific to a technical user.  I am just looking for a definition of Parse.  By that logic the user does not Upload the file but most users know what upload means in computer terms.

Comment: @Frisbee I understand what you are asking. But for this to be a UX question, we really do need to understand the bigger picture here. Context is everything. If you're simply looking for a generic definition, then I don't think this is a UX question and probably belongs on english.se

Comment: (For example, I don't see a strong difference between 'parsing a sentence' and 'parsing a xml file' from a user-centric point of view.)

Comment: @DA01 I wish it was that easy.  My users can parse a sentence but they really have trouble abstracting that term to a computer parse.  That is why I want to use parse as once they get it they will get it.  They can use a double negative in sentence with ease but they cannot not follow it in search logic.   I use analyze, process, and analytics so need a fresh term.   Once the connect with a term they seem to get it.

Comment: @Frisbee that's actually *exactly* the type of context we're talking about. Seems you have a very specific user type and that helps define the context. So, I'd ask: Why is it important for users to understand this term? How does it help the complete their task? What is their desired end result? What kind of file are they having the system parse for them?

Comment: It is a formal step between Load (text file from disk) and Upload (the parsed output to the shared repository).  The can tweak some parse options.  They validate the parsed output is "OK".  I know how to describe it in general.  I need a def for Parse.   If I was a doc what is a not medical definition of anurism?  Because my users are control freaks and they want a sense of what any button does - they want to feel in control.

Comment: Based on all of that, I'm not sure I'd use the term 'parse' at all. What about 'convert file'?

Comment: @DA01 Thanks for your time and thank you for your input.  I am not asking what to call it.  Technically it is a parse - straight up no question.   Nothing is changed - it is not a convert.  I am simply asking how to define parse in lay terms.

Comment: I know, and I don't mean to purposefully frustrate you, but realize you are asking a bunch of UX people. And UX people will likely tell you to not use the technical term in the first place if it has to be defined for people to understand it. As such, I don't think this is a UX question. I do strongly suggest asking this over on english.se You might get a better answer there.

Comment: @DA01 Cool I appreciate your time.  I can get generic def of parse from the the dictionary.  My problem here is that I am trying to lead them down a road road of proper technical terms.  Have some users that know the actual terms.   We do some advanced statistics and use the proper term so if they go to Wikipedia they can look up what is does.  Maybe not the correct approach but that is the path we are on.  Other products use some black box feel good terms but on the other end they have reporting bodies that are technical and ask the hard questions.

Comment: Suggestion: also post this question on http://english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @PixelSnader I was hoping for computer perspective that I kind of got.

Comment: @frisbee my point is that you're asking computer savvy people to come up with a term for non-computer savvy people. (albeit that these particular savvy ones are more aware of the unsavvy) If a group of regular people can come up with a term they understand, it's more likely the general populace will understand as well. At any rate it's an extra perspective and gives you the opportunity to cross-reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your purposes, parse can be defined as: converting data that is in one format into another format that the computer prefers. You might add that some data may be lost in the conversion.

Comment: Like that definition.  Don't lose anything as nothing the thrown out.  If the line does not parse they just get the raw input.  Kind of why I need them to have a basic understanding of parse.

Answer (score 8):

How about "when you upload the file, our program will interpret and process the information, creating the most appropriate layout"? Or a different phrase touching on the input, processing, and output? "Our program" may not be the correct description depending on what you are working on.

Comment: Not trying describe what the overall program does.  Just the word Parse.  They are ware of the the input and output.  They are aware to not upload if the output looks wrong.  It is not the most appropriate layout - it is right or wrong.

Comment: Could you just use "process and interpret the information"?

Comment: Maybe that is the best way to go about it.  I am not a UX guy.  I come at it from the technical side.  I am looking for something a little more technical.  My users seem to like a feel for what is actually going on - in control.

Comment: @Frisbee What are the three types of lines? Integer and two others?

Comment: Integer is an external example.  I am not trying to describe the overall program or even how THIS parse works.  What would be a good definition / explanation of the word "Parse" for non-technical users?

Comment: Ok. From a UX perspective, if the user doesn't need to know anything about how the parsing works, I would keep the explanation as simple as possible - "process and interpret the information".

Answer (score 3):

### read

If it is absolutely necessary to separate the actions of uploading and parsing, then I recommend you say something like *we will attempt to read your file with the following settings* above the form to set the parsing options.

It's a simple metaphor, that any user who can read the instruction is guaranteed to understand.

Comment: Simple metaphor ANY user guaranteed to understand?  Not my users.

Comment: What I meant was that if they can read, they'll know what the word "read" means. Something you can't say for "interpret", "parse" or "analyze". It doesn't have to be technically correct, it needs to convey the message well enough that users will understand that this is what they're looking for. The behavior of the application and the associated form will tell them the rest. If you are worried that users will misinterpret the message, you should do some quick testing with a paper mockup.

Comment: It is an app that does a lot of advanced stuff for non-technical users and we pick specific terms.  Some times technical and some times not technical but try an be consistent.  We have search, analytics, score, match, and predict.  Parse is unique and something they have not done before in this application.  We will use parse as a verb in other contexts so want to introduce the term properly.

Comment: @Frisbee I see. Then I misunderstood your question, sorry. I thought you were looking for something to replace _parse_, rather than explain it. _"To read a file"_ might still suffice as an explanation, but it may be too simple for your context. Paper testing should help decide between your favorite options.

Answer (score 1):

"Process" may be the most accurate word for "parse" but you can also see whether "Analyze," "Inspect," or "Examine" can work for your users.  It's a little more common to see those on buttons on some of the tools that I've seen.

Best way is try it out with a user and see whether it makes sense to them.  I'd probably keep the button to a one word verb and optionally put descriptive text under it.

The descriptive text can read: "Click the Analyze button to verify the format, layout, and accuracy of your file.  You may upload the file with the suggested corrections once complete."

Although you're really doing things like "pattern-recognition," I would venture to guess that your non-technical users wouldn't care about that level of detail.  You'll probably lose them if you name the button "Parse" too.

Comment: I am not looking for another word.  I am looking for definition to Parse.

Comment: You may want to rename the title of this question to what you are exactly seeking

Comment: "What would be a good definition / explanation of Parse?"  "I am just trying to describe what this Parse button.."

Comment: added some sample text

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest definition is to analyze a string of information into its parts and describe their syntactic roles.

Comment: Syntactic roles is not the right direction.

Comment: This answer functions more as a comment. If you can please elaborate on your answer.